# VNC clipboard not working

Tags: linux, vnc, subshell

If I uncomment the two lines in my `~/.vnc/xstartup` that enable 'normal' desktop environment for VNC, the `vncconfig -iconic &` command is ignored:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
#unset SESSION_MANAGER
#exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
xterm -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
twm &
```

If run without the desktop environment in VNC, the config is called, and my VNC clipboard works fine.

I would like to run the desktop environment and still have vncconfig loaded.

Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal because the `exec` command means "stop executing this script and replace it (in memory) by the command parameter script".

If you uncomment the `exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` line, everything after that line will never be executed.

I do not know the content of your `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` so I cannot be exhaustive but, probably, you need to carefully read it and copy in `~/.vnc/xstartup` the minimal needed configuration (instead of uncommenting the exec line).